# SNMPD on boot is not working as expected

Tags: 14.04, configuration, snmp

I am monitoring some computers on my enterprise network via SNMP.
For some reason the SNMPD service is not working as expected after reboot on Ubuntu hosts.

Looking at `pstree`, I can see the snmpd service started under `init` root node, but requests going to this host fail.
If I restart the service with `service snmpd restart`, it comes under the `lightdm/init` node and works as expected.

Is there something I am missing to make `snmpd` start on boot?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with the gnome-shell interface.

Answer (score 1):

First Cheeck whether snmpd service is started on boot using below command.

```
service --status-all
```

If snmpd is enable to start on boot,You will see. ( + sign for enable , -  sign for disable)

> [ + ] snmpd

You can put snmpd in startup using this command.

```
update-rc.d snmpd defaults
```

Comment: Hi Patel, thanks for your answer.

snmpd is already enabled. When I try to use update-rc.d, a message saying something like "this service already is on rc.d" is displayed...

Answer (score 0):

My `snmpd.conf` file was configured using `snmpconf` command. When I configured it first, I set the community AND hostname from machine who can monitor.

For some reason (I don't know why), setting that hostname unable snmp monitoring on boot (restarting the service works well). If I specify only my community string, snmpd works as expected.